# Can $1/n$ be written as the sum of integer multiples of reciprical primes?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Is
$$\frac{1}{n} = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{p_i}$$
for some $a:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$, and some $p:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}_p$, where $p$ is strictly increasing and $-p_i < a_i< p_i$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$, true for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$? It seems intuitively true and I could not find any easy method to prove or disprove the statement. Of course if $n$ is prime, the statement is trivial. Have any suggested approaches and/or have a proof?
$$$$I did a bit of searching but could not find anything which gives a result similar to this (maybe I'm not sure what to search for), if you have a reference that addresses this problem that would be great. I came across this problem as a lemma for another proof, and if this is true, it seems like there might be some interesting consequences.

Comment: Yes for an infinite sum, even if the $a_i$ are restricted to $0$ and $1$.  The same can be said for all positive reals.

Comment: Awesome! have a reference handy or a keyword to search?

Comment: It seems obvious.  For example $\frac14=\frac{1}{5}+ \frac{1}{23}+ \frac{1}{157}+ \frac{1}{6569}+ \frac{1}{12164459}+ \frac{1}{8004786706057}+ \cdots$ using a greedy algorithm

Comment: Oh true, I had not actually thought about it because I wasn't sure where to start. But I guess it is somewhat trivial as the sequence of partial sums can always be made less then some epsilon since the sum of reciprocal primes diverges (which also makes it true for any real number)... should I delete the question? I still am not sure exactly how to prove the statement though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The sum of the reciprocals of all prime numbers diverges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes) so there is a simple greedy algorithm which works for any target which is a positive real:

1. Start with your target $t$
2. Find the smallest prime $p$ greater than or equal to $\frac1t$ and any primes you have already used
3. If $\frac1p \not = t$ then $0 < t-\frac1p < t$ and you can repeat the steps with the new target $t-\frac1p$

The (possibly infinite) sum of the reciprocals of the primes found will therefore give the original target, and this algorithm amounts to a proof.

So for example,

- starting with a target of $\frac14$, the first prime to use is $5$
- giving a new target of $\frac14-\frac15=\frac1{20}$ and the second prime to use is $23$
- giving a new target of $\frac1{20}-\frac1{23}=\frac{3}{460} \approx \frac{1}{153.333}$ and the third prime to use is $157$
- ...

leading to $$\frac14=\frac{1}{5}+ \frac{1}{23}+ \frac{1}{157}+ \frac{1}{6569}+ \frac{1}{12164459}+ \frac{1}{8004786706057}+ \cdots$$